# TVout characters don't line up

Tags: arduino-nano, library

I am messing around with the Arduino TVout library and I have created some multi-character tiles (I don't know what else to call them). Just to start out, I created a simple X that spans across 4 characters but when I print them to the screen they align correctly.

How they should align:
[image]

How they really align:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

Main file:

```cpp
#include "expressions.h"
#include <TVout.h>

TVout win;
unsigned char x = 0, y = 0;

void setup() {
  win.begin(NTSC);
  win.select_font(expr8x8);
}

void loop() {
  win.clear_screen();
  x = 2, y = 5;
  print_char(0, x, y);

  win.delay(1);
}

void print_char(char c, int startx, int starty) {
  int tmpx = startx, tmpy = starty;
  for (char i = c; i < c + 4; i++) {
    win.print_char(tmpx * 8, tmpy * 8, i);
    if (++tmpx == c + 2) {
      tmpy++;
      tmpx = startx;
    }
  }
}
```

expressions.h

```
#define EXPRESSIONS8x8_H

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
extern const unsigned char expr8x8[];
```

expressions.cpp

```cpp
#include "expressions.h"

PROGMEM const unsigned char expr8x8[] = {
  8, 8, 0, // width, height, start
 
  // broken
  0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x38, 0x1c, 0x1e, 0x07, 0x03,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x1c, 0x38, 0x70, 0xe0, 0xc0,
  0x03, 0x07, 0x0e, 0x1c, 0x38, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00,
  0xc0, 0xc0, 0x70, 0x38, 0x1c, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x00,

  // happy
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x1f, 0x38, 0x70,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0xf8, 0x1c, 0x0e,
  0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? How do I fix this bug/issue?

Comment: Less lines of code would be to just have 4 prints, one for each character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is in this line:

```cpp
if (++tmpx == c + 2) {
```

Here you are mixing two different things:

- `c` is a character code, i.e. the index of a glyph within the
  `expr8x8` font
- `tmpx` is the index of a character cell (a 8×8 block of pixels) within
  a line of the screen

Comparing those makes little sense. And in fact, the comparison will
always be false, as `c` is zero, and `tmpx` starts at 2 and increases
from there.

I guess what you meant was:

```cpp
if (++tmpx == startx + 2) {
```